# Java complex arrays

Tags: java

I have a main array in the program that the user gives the index of via textfield:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
      import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
      import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Main {

static JTextArea results = new JTextArea();
static int Gen = 0;
static JLabel l4 = new JLabel("  Generated: "+Gen);
static JFrame w = new JFrame("Final");
static JTextField t3 = new JTextField();
static String[] values = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L","M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0","1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};


public static void main(String[] args){

    JPanel a = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Size:");
    t3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 100, 20));
    JButton start = new JButton("Start!");
    results.setToolTipText("This is where the generated keys will be displayed");
    start.addActionListener(new startClicked());
    a.add(l3);
    a.add(t3);
    a.add(start);

    w.add(a, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    w.add(l4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(results);
    w.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    results.setEditable(false);
    w.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    w.setVisible(true);
    w.setResizable(true);
    w.setSize(new Dimension( 600, 400));
    w.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
}

static class startClicked implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(t3.getText().isEmpty() != true){
            compile();
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No number");
        }
    }
}

public static void compile(){

}

public static char[] genNext(char[] s){

    for(int i = 0; i<=s.length; i++){
        if(s[i]=='Z'){
            s[i] = 0;
            incr(s[i+1]);
            return s;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static char incr(char c){
    return c;
}
    }
```

when a button is pressed it gets the number typed into the box as the array's index: so i.e : 5 then the array is [0,0,0,0,0]

The first or last 0 in the array(array[0] or array[4]) is then replaced by '0'-'9' then followed by 'a'-'z'.

So [0,0,0,0,0] will be [0,0,0,0,1] and when its done it will be [0,0,0,0,Z].

Now when that index is 'Z' the index previous will be 0 then repeats as previous but 'Z' gets reset back to 'A' then it repeats back to 'Z'

So this is what it will look like in a since:

Start [0,0,0,0,0]
Finished [Z,Z,Z,Z,Z]

and all of the outcomes should be displayed in a textarea on a new line.

Any and all help is appreciated

**Solutions to this can be complex or simple, as long as

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how exactly would i be able to make an array generate all possible values from A-Z on each index and when it does get to 'Z', it will make the previous index go to A and etc. [000] will be [00Z] then the next one in order will be [0A0] until [0AZ] then [0BA] and etc. untilt the ending result is [ZZZ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this might help:

```
long start = 0;
long stop = Long.parseLong("ZZZZZ", 36);

for (long i = start; i <= stop; ++i)
{
    System.out.println(Long.toString(i, 36).toUpperCase());
}
```